# i2c does not detect hat

Tags: pi-3, i2c

I have the following set-up. A RaspberryPi3 and on top of it I placed the Adafruit DC motor hat.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aZzkP7p.jpg]

I enabled the I2C from Raspi-Config, installed python-smbus and i2c tools, added the `i2c-bcm2708&nbsp;i2c-dev` in `/etc/modules`.

When I run in the command line `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` I see only dashes, so no adress is in use. I tried running the command with the Sensehat on and I saw some addresses being used.

How can I fix the issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What issue?  You need to explain what you have physically connected to the Pi, what i2c_detect shows, and what you expect it to show.  You also need to tell us basic things like the results of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/os-release`.  A photo may also be useful.

Comment: I am out of edits, but the picture link is in the text.  It just needs a little reformatting to make it show correctly.

Comment: You are saying that it does detect something when the hat is turned on?

Comment: Yes. I was following this guide, [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c) and when I ran sudo i2cdetect -y 1 i would get no addresses being used. Then I soldered the pins and now I have two addresses are in use 0x60 and 0x70.